# I used CGPath to make a picture with 4 CALayers, how can I zoom in and out?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cgpath, cashapelayer

I used CGPath to make a picture with 4 CALayers, how can I zoom in and out?

The picture contained a four different circles, a rectangle, and a more complicated shape.However, I want to make it zoom in and out like UIRefreshControl. 
It's unrealistic to control every shape at the same time to make it look like the original.

Comment: dont get it. put it in a scrollview

Answer (score 0):

If you need it:
in your `drawInRect:` method you can add `CGContextScaleCTM (yourContext,scaleX,scaleY);` when scaleX and scaleY are  CGFloat. Experiment with it. For example you can set scale with a UISlider.